# btc-e current btc withdrawal fee

Tags: btce, exchange-fees

Hello can anyone answer me whats the current btc-e withdrawal fee?
The only source of information i can find is [this](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/BTC-E) which says it's set to 0.01 btc. Is it still valid?

Comment: there are multiple methods of withdrawal transactions that very based upon the method chosen

Answer (score 1):

You can see current fees only after registration on the btc-e.

Follow to "Finances", click "Withdraw" in the Bitcoin line.

Or login and follow the link:
https://btc-e.com/profile#funds/withdraw_coin/1

> - Min amount for withdrawal - 0.002 BTC.
> - Be patient, transfer of funds will be before the first confirmation.
> - Fee for withdrawal is 0.001 BTC.
> - Daily limit on withdrawal - 100 BTC.

Ways and fees to withdraw and to deposit are often subject to change on btc-e, thought for a long while (longer than 2 years) the Bitcoin withdraw fee is stay the same: **0.001 BTC**.

When btc-e change rates, add new withdraw or deposit method - they usually tweet about it. 
https://twitter.com/btcecom
Sometimes they also can add a piece of "news" when a fee is changed: https://btc-e.com/news

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to withdraw from BTC-E however since you asked specifically in terms of BTC the current withdraw fee (Dec 13, 2013) is stated on the website:

```
* Fee for withdrawal is 0.001 BTC.
```

Comment: Where do you see this stated on the site? It doesn't appear under FAQ nor is it in their withdrawal section of the site.